# new Date(new Date().getTime()-25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) got unexpected date

Tags: java, android

I would like to generate a list of dates, but found out the date is wrong start from - 25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

My local date is 2016-07-17. I got

```
2016-07-17
2016-07-16
2016-07-15
...
2016-06-23
2016-08-11
```

I have no idea where the `2016-08-11` comes from. I broke down the 25 to 24 and -1 as below (`xxx` and `yyy`), and then I got the correct date `2016-06-22`.

Why does `xxx` work but `yyy` Doesn't?

```
Date xxx = new Date(new Date().getTime()-24 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 -1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
Date yyy = new Date(new Date().getTime()-25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Here is my code: date is wrong from i=25

```
for (int i=0; i<240;i++) {
    Date dt = new Date(new Date().getTime() - i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Log.e(TAG,Global.sdfDateTime19.format(dt));
}
```

Comment: Is this `java.sql.Date`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're overflowing the range of `int`. `i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` yields an `int` (which is then subtracted from the `long` from `getDate`).

It's okay when `i` is 24, because the result is 2,073,600,000, which is less than the maximum positive value for an `int`, 2,147,483,647. But when you reach `i = 25`, you wrap around (the value if you weren't constrained to `int` would be 2,160,000,000, which is too big).

Just make it a `long` multiplication, either by declaring `i` as a long or by making the 24 a `long`:

```
Date dt = new Date(new Date().getTime() - i * 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000);
// ---------------------------------------------^
```

> Why xxx works but yyy not work?

Because you've broken up the multiplication into two parts *(I've added a space in there for clarity, since the `-1` otherwise looks like a negative number rather than the subtraction operator followed by `1`)*:

```
Date xxx = new Date(new Date().getTime()-24 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
// The first part -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// The second part ------------------------------------------------/
```

... and neither of the two parts you've broken it up into overflows the range of `int`.

---

In general, I wouldn't suggest manipulating dates this way, not least because not all days have exactly 24 hours in them (consider the days going into and out of daylight saving time). I'd use a library that lets you work at the "day" level, such as the Java 8 `java.time` stuff, or JodaTime, or similar.

Comment: This is the right answer - but I would suggest to use a library ( like threetenabp ) for this kind of calculation

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot! I really need to know more JAVA.

Answer (score 2):

Integer overflow.

Multiplying `25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` results in `2160000000` which is more than what fits in an integer.

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

Much easier to use [`minusDays( 1 )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays-long-) on [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); // Better to pass the optional `ZoneId`.
for (int i=0; i<240; i++) {
    LocalDate localDate = today.minusDays( i );
    System.out.println( localDate.toString() );
    …
}
```

### Back-ported to Android

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).